# How to ignore the empty line at the end of input

Tags: c++, input, newline, cin

The following code works fine and also check if user has input right amount of items, but it fails when the input has a trailing empty line.

```
string item1, item2, item3;
while(cin.good) {

    //this allows me to both check if user input enough items 
    //EDIT: and if items are of right type so I can cerr
    if (cin >> item1 && cin>> item2 && cin>> item3) {

        doStuff(item1,item2,item3);

    }else {

        cerr<<"bad input! Not enough input items or wrong type"<<endl;

    }

}
```

Can I change cin.good to something else to solve the situation when there is a trailing empty line? I'll accept other solutions too.

EDIT:
I realize I can't use while(cin >> item1) because then I can't cerr the error message if item1 is wrong type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that:

```
while(cin >> item1) {
    //this allows me to check if user input enough items
    if (cin >> item2 && cin >> item3) {
        doStuff(item1,item2,item3);
    } else {
        cerr<<"bad input! Not enough input items"<<endl;
    }
}
```

will do what you want.

Comment: sorry, but I just realize I need the original if statement because I also need to check and cerr the correctness of item type.